# Do I need to go through security at Newark airport after flying in from NC before boarding international flight to Ireland?

Tags: airport-security, united-airlines, connecting-flights, ewr

I will be flying from Asheville, NC to Newark with a 2 1/2 hours layover before boarding United airlines to Dublin, Ireland.

Will I need to go through security again?  I will not have checked baggage.  I am an older woman with a bit of difficulty walking.  What is the easiest way to get from one terminal to another?

Comment: If you require assistance, can you not book a buggy or cart ride through the airline during your transfer?

Comment: Is United also operating the Asheville to Newark flight?

Comment: In the US there's often no sterile transit (aka international transit zones). You would have to go through security again then. Sometimes you don't have to do it in domestic flights.

Comment: Johns, United is operating the Asheville to Newark flight so it's United all the way from Asheville to Dublin.

Comment: Moo, I'll definitely book a cart ride. Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

United Airlines operates out of all 3 terminals at EWR - terminals A, B and C - although the majority of flights arrive and depart out of Terminal C, and it's highly likely that both of your flights will be out of that terminal.

All 3 terminals are connected air-side by a shuttle bus. When using this bus, there is no need to re-clear security as it is air-side in all terminals.

All 3 terminals are also connected by an airtrain. This airtrain is outside of security, and thus if you catch it you will need to re-clear security.  For this reason, if you do need to change terminals then taking the bus is recommended.

Looking at your specific flights today as an example, the flight from AVL landed at gate C109, whilst the flight to Dublin left from C82.  These are both in the same terminal (C), however they are a fair distance apart.

To get between gates in terminal C (including gate that the bus goes to/from if you need to go between terminals) there are 'golf' carts available that will take you to your gate - simple flag one down, or ask the staff at the gate and they will contact one for you.

You can also contact the airline in advance and request a wheelchair, but unless you have severe difficulty walking this will likely end up being more of an annoyance than just using the carts.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the AirTrain to connect between the airline terminals free of charge at Newark Airport but you will have to go through security again unlike most airports in the USA if you are changing terminal in Newark. If you are in the same terminal you can walk to your gate or ask for assistance.

2 and a half hours should be enough time to get to another terminal and through security again. You can always ask for assistance to help as you have difficulty walking.

Will you be flying from Dublin which is in Republic of Ireland to the UK? If so you will have to go through Irish Immigration and security before flying to the UK, when you land in the UK there will be no immigration as the UK and Republic of Ireland are part of the Common Travel Area.

PS if you are actually only going to Dublin in the Republic of Ireland and not the UK do not call Ireland part of the UK as it may offend some Irish people.

Comment: It depends if she has to change terminals in Newark. If she doesn't, she's good. I can never remember which airline goes to which terminal.

Comment: This answer is outright WRONG.  There is NO NEED TO RECLEAR SECURITY when chaining between UA flights (and UA is the only airline that flies from Asheville to EWR)

Comment: @Doc: Wikipedia says that Allegiant also flies AVE-EWR (though I agree that's an unlikely itinerary).

Comment: @Doc I said if changing terminal on the airtrain... I think your answer is a lot better and will up it... my part regarding Dublin and the UK is all correct. although he might not fly to the UK she may get a ferry or drive or train it to Northern Ireland which is part of the UK

Comment: @SamJones The question wasn't whether you need to re-clear security when using the airtrain, the question was whether you need to re-clear security.  Whilst your answer is technically correct when read in isolation, it's wrong as an answer to the question that was being ask.

Comment: @NateEldredge Good point, I had missed that one.  But the timing means that it's clearly not the flights the person is on.

Comment: @Doc I used the Airtrain when I was there, I didn't know about the bus and wasn't in a real rush. Thank you for your comments though, you will have helped OP a lot

Comment: Thank you!  This helps. Sam, thanks for the info on immigration through Dublin.  That works well since I have a long layover in Dublin before traveling to UK.

Answer (score 1):

When using the Shuttle Bus to transfer between terminals A B and C at Newark you do not need to pass through / redo security. This is different from the Airtrain (for which you will have to redo security) Look for the signs, I’ve posted a photo of what the signs look like. Hope this helps :) [image: A photo of the Shuttle Transfer signs at Newark]